# Frustum culling - error evaluating a point in the plane of the frustum

Tags: opengl, culling, frustum

I am trying to implement the following code:

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/geometric-approach-implementation/

I need to use frustum culling in my graphics engine.

my functions are:

```
void frustum::updateCameraData()
{
    float _ratio = float(globalData::windowWidth/globalData::windowHeight);
    // store the information
    this->ratio = _ratio;
    this->angle = globalData::cameraAngle;
    this->nearD = globalData::zNear;
    this->farD = globalData::zFar;

    // compute width and height of the near and far m_frustumane sections
    tang = (float)tan(PI * globalData::cameraAngle * 0.5) ;
    nh = nearD * tang;
    nw = nh * _ratio;
    fh = farD  * tang;
    fw = fh * _ratio;

}

    void frustum::extractFrustum(vector3f camPosition, vector3f camDirection, vector3f camUp)
{
    cout << "camPosition = ";
    camPosition.print();
    cout << " camDirection = ";
    camDirection.print();
    cout << " camUp = ";
    camUp.print();
    cout << "\n";
    vector3f dir,nc,fc,X,Y,Z,Zn;


    // compute the Z axis of camera
    // this axis points in the opposite direction from
    // the looking direction
    Z = camPosition - camDirection;
    Z.Normalize();

    // X axis of camera with given "up" vector and Z axis
    X = camUp * Z;
    X.Normalize();

    // the real "up" vector is the cross product of Z and X
    Y = Z * X;

    // compute the centers of the near and far planes
    nc = camPosition - Z * nearD;
    fc = camPosition - Z * farD;

    // compute the 4 corners of the frustum on the near plane
    ntl = nc + Y * nh - X * nw;
    ntr = nc + Y * nh + X * nw;
    nbl = nc - Y * nh - X * nw;
    nbr = nc - Y * nh + X * nw;

    // compute the 4 corners of the frustum on the far plane
    ftl = fc + Y * fh - X * fw;
    ftr = fc + Y * fh + X * fw;
    fbl = fc - Y * fh - X * fw;
    fbr = fc - Y * fh + X * fw;



    Zn = vector3f(-Z.x,-Z.y,-Z.z);
    m_frustum[NEARP].setNormalAndPoint(Zn,nc);
    m_frustum[FARP].setNormalAndPoint(Z,fc);

    vector3f aux,normal;

    aux = (nc + Y*nh) - camPosition;
    aux.Normalize();
    normal = aux * X;
    Zn = nc+Y*nh;
    m_frustum[TOP].setNormalAndPoint(normal,Zn);

    aux = (nc - Y*nh) - camPosition;
    aux.Normalize();
    normal = X * aux;

    Zn = nc-Y*nh;
    m_frustum[BOTTOM].setNormalAndPoint(normal,Zn);

    aux = (nc - X*nw) - camPosition;
    aux.Normalize();
    normal = aux * Y;

    Zn = nc-X*nw;
    m_frustum[LEFT].setNormalAndPoint(normal,Zn);

    aux = (nc + X*nw) - camPosition;
    aux.Normalize();
    normal = Y * aux;

    Zn = nc+X*nw;
    m_frustum[RIGHT].setNormalAndPoint(normal,Zn);

}

bool frustum::pointInFrustum( float x, float y, float z )
{
    vector3f point = vector3f(x,y,z);

    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << "m_frustum[i].distance(point) = "<< m_frustum[i].distance(point) <<" < 0\n";
        if (m_frustum[i].distance(point) < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}



/*this is used to calculate the distance of point to plane*/

float distance(vector3f &p) {

    return (d + normal.innerProduct(p));
}
```

however, I get unwanted results (this are my debug messages):

```
   camPosition = (0, 15, 40) camDirection = (0, 0, 0) camUp = (0, 1, 0)

NO DRAWN: object0
posicion: -20,0,-20
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(-20,0,-20)
m_frustum[0].distance(point) = 14.7867 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(-20,0,-20)
m_frustum[1].distance(point) = 14.485 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(-20,0,-20)
m_frustum[2].distance(point) = 14.2216 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(-20,0,-20)
m_frustum[3].distance(point) = -15.0501 < 0
NO DRAWN: object1
posicion: 0,0,-20
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(0,0,-20)
m_frustum[0].distance(point) = 14.7867 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(0,0,-20)
m_frustum[1].distance(point) = 14.485 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(0,0,-20)
m_frustum[2].distance(point) = 14.2216 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(0,0,-20)
m_frustum[3].distance(point) = -15.0501 < 0
NO DRAWN: object2
posicion: 20,0,-7
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(20,0,-7)
m_frustum[0].distance(point) = 14.7867 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(20,0,-7)
m_frustum[1].distance(point) = 14.485 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(20,0,-7)
m_frustum[2].distance(point) = 14.2216 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(20,0,-7)
m_frustum[3].distance(point) = -15.0501 < 0
NO DRAWN: object3
posicion: -40,0,-20
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(-40,0,-20)
m_frustum[0].distance(point) = 14.7867 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(-40,0,-20)
m_frustum[1].distance(point) = 14.485 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(-40,0,-20)
m_frustum[2].distance(point) = 14.2216 < 0
/*object position*/ vector3f point = vector3f(-40,0,-20)
m_frustum[3].distance(point) = -15.0501 < 0
```

None of the objects passed the test (I test with pointInFrustrum(), using the point as position of each object.

if I render the scene without frustum culling, everything looks perfect, but to use it, nothing passes the test. any idea where can be the error? (the code is that the link which I have mentioned above).

All  objects are with in visual field...

The matrix is managed with glm::mat4;

EDIT:

After I have made the corrections, if I point the camera a bit downward, the objects are drawn, but if I point the camera a bit up, all the objects disappear completely (They are not drawn this time). Do you know what may be happening? Thanks in advance.

if the camera points downward:

[image]

if the camera points a bit up:

[image]

Comment: You might have more luck on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com even if this isn't for a game.

Comment: Where do `nw` and `nh` come from? They seem to show up out of nowhere in the code you posted.

Comment: I added the function where nw and nh is initialized, you can see it in the post (updateCameraData()).

I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: thanks, I could finally solve the problem. it resided in the calculation of the planes (i wasn't using the matrices as i should do), i change it and everything worked perfect. Thank you very much to all !.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally solve the problem. It resided in the calculation of the planes (I wasn't using the matrices as I should), I changed it and everything worked perfect.